# Moving tr's between tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jinja2

I have an application that auto generates X number of tables, and assigns them random id's depending on their value. I then have one main table that acts as a data pool, where data is stored before it is dropped into a new table.

Eventually once data is stored it its new table, it will be order-able, so I can change the hierarchy of the table. Also it should be able to be moved out of its table and in to any other table. I plan to use a small button/image to move the data up and down inside each table, but moving from one table to another should just be able to function on clicking on the row.

All of the tutorials and code snippets I have seen online show moving data between tables, but in your jquery script you have to manually assign all table classes and id's. Which I cannot do as they are variable as to what is returned from an initial SQL query.

My current html template looks like this (i know it wont work, but the draggable and droppable are just to show you how I would like it to work). Is this even possible with jquery, or should I be looking down another route?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
});
</script>

{% for vehicle in vehicles %} <!-- List the vehicles available -->
<h1>{{ vehicle.reg }} </h1>
<table class="listing droppable" id="{{ vehicle.reg }}">
<tr>
<th>Account #</th>
<th>Customer</th>
<th>Order #</th>
<th>Order Weight</th>
</tr>
<!-- want items to be dropped as rows in here -->
</table>
<br /><br />
{% endfor %}

<br /><br />
<h1>Unassigned Orders</h1>
<table class="listing">
<tr>
<th>Account #</th>
<th>Customer</th>
<th>Order #</th>
<th>Order Weight</th>
</tr>
{% for order in orders %}
<tr class="draggable"> <!-- rows should be able to get dropped into any vehicle table -->
<td>{{ order.oh_custaccref }}</td> <!-- and then into any other table (if required) -->
<td>{{ order.name }}</td> 
<td>{{ order.oh_orderno }}</td>  
<td>{{ order.oh_orderwgt }}</td>  
</tr>

{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this with http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/

Its a really cool extension which lets you move cells, and entire rows within and between tables.

My html template ended up becoming:

```
<div id="drag">
{% for vehicle in vehicles %} <!-- List the vehicles available -->
<table class="listing" id="{{ vehicle.reg }}">
<colgroup><col width="100"/><col width="120"/><col width="480"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/></colgroup>
<tr>
<th class="mark">{{ vehicle.reg }}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="mark">  </th>    
<th class="mark">Account #</th>
<th class="mark">Customer</th>
<th class="mark">Order #</th>
<th class="mark">Order Weight</th>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td class="rowhandler"><div class="drag row"></div> </td> 
<td></td> 
<td></td> 
<td></td>  
<td></td>
</tr>
<!-- want items to be dropped as rows in here -->
</table>
{% endfor %}

<table class="listing">
<colgroup><col width="100"/><col width="120"/><col width="480"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/></colgroup>
<tr>
<th class="mark">NO REG</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="mark">  </th>    
<th class="mark">Account #</th>
<th class="mark">Customer</th>
<th class="mark">Order #</th>
<th class="mark">Order Weight</th>
</tr>   
{% for order in orders %}
<tr> 
<!-- rows should be able to get dropped into any vehicle table -->
<td class="rowhandler"><div class="drag row"></div> </td> 
<td>{{ order.oh_custaccref }}</td> <!-- and then into any other table (if required) -->
<td>{{ order.name }}</td> 
<td>{{ order.oh_orderno }}</td>  
<td>{{ order.oh_orderwgt }}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}    
</table>
</div> <!-- end drag -->
{% endblock %}
```